# How to get a path to file written out by Part of multipart Servlet 3.0 request?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, multipartform-data, servlet-3.0

I'm writing Spring MVC controller that will accept multipart file uploads (the standard way to upload a file from HTML form).

Servlet 3.0 specification introduced standard way for servlet containers to handle multipart/form-data with introduction of [MultipartConfigElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/MultipartConfigElement.html) for configuration and [Part](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html%20Part) interface and Spring MVC integrates with these with no problems.

The problem: I want to get full path to file that is being output by `Part.write()` method, skipping unnecessary `InputStream` reading. The files uploaded to my controller, due to their size, will most probably end up as temporary files output to disk by servlet container, therefore `Part.write()` will move the file into target name instead of misusing RAM resources. The file, according to specification, is written relative to configured multipart location.

The solution I came up with is this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/upload")
public class UploadController {
    @Autowired
    private MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{uploadId}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleMultipartFileUpload(
            @PathVariable String uploadId,
            @RequestParam("file") List<Part> files) throws IOException {
        for (Part uploadedPart : files) {
            String temporaryFileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            uploadedPart.write(temporaryFileName);

            // CODE-SMELL FOLLOWS:
            Path temporaryFilePath = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(
                    multipartConfigElement.getLocation()).resolve(temporaryFileName);
        }

        return "handleMultipartFileUpload";
    }
}
```

The code-smell comment above is just this: code smell. I create the path to written file using autowired `MultipartConfigElement` that Spring happens to have as a bean. The question is:

1. **Is there a better way to get location where files are written?**
2. What about application that does not use Spring and doesn't have access to injected `MultipartConfigElement` bean?